# On $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p_1+\cdots+p_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p_1\cdots p_n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, transcendental-number-theory

For $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime number.

**Question**. Are the two numbers

$$c_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p_1+\cdots+p_n}\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ c_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p_1\cdots p_n}$$
transcendental?

I believe that the answer is positive. My computation suggests $c_1\approx 1.023476$.

If the question is too difficult, can one prove that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are irrational?

Comment: Why they are better than any other random numbers?

Comment: Have you tried to examine the corresponding continued fractions?

Comment: $c_2$ is irrational and which follows same idea of this paper: https://people.ohio.edu/diao/papers/Irrationality%20of%20e.pdf

Comment: I do not know how to prove that $c_1$ is irrational (if it is actually.)
The proof that $c_2$ is irrational is already published here: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/9929-on-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-primorials/56ECB260FAE52588FCECE9AAAAB2695D.